# Adding button above an image in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

I'm using image-map-pro-jquery-interactive-image and  trying to add a button above the image but it won't show.

```
 var div1=document.getElementById("wcp-editor-canvas");
     console.log(div1)
     div1.innerHTML+='<button style="position:absolute;">Do it</button>';
```

Any solution?

Comment: please provide a [js-fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) to better illustrate the case

Comment: Use `insertAdjacentHTML` instead as it gives you greater control of where the HTML string will be inserted. So an example would be `div1.insertAdjacentHTML('afterBegin', '<button style="position:absolute;">Do it</button>')`

Comment: insertAdjacentHTML doesnt work for me

Comment: @KAD — Stackoverflow has supported [inline live demos](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) for **years**. There's no need to resort to hosting the demo externally.

Comment: @LaamiriOussema — Try providing a [mcve]. It is hard to tell what the problem is from just that tiny fragment of code.

Answer (score 0):

Change the position to relative and set the style to `"display: block; position: relative"`The button is being covered because the position is absolute which means that this element doesn't have a position in the layout. Also the innerHTML needs to be stored in a variable which is equal to `buttonHTMLString + innerHTML` this puts the button HTML in front of the other HTML within.